# How to calculate boundary points of numerical derivative in python?

Tags: python, arrays, math, numerical-methods

I'm trying to write a function to take the derivative of any general function / array of numbers. Specifically, I am using a [Central difference formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation). The issue is, I cannot compute the boundary points of the derivative as the central difference formula uses indices that would be out of bound. My code is below

```
import numpy as np
n = 20000 # number of points in array
xs = np.linspace(start=-2*np.pi, stop=2*np.pi, num=n) # x values
y = np.array([np.sin(i) for i in xs]) # our function, sine

def deriv(f, h):
    """
    Calauclate the numerical derivative of any function
    :param f: numpy.array(float), the array of numbers we differentiate
    :param h: step size
    :rtype d: numpy.array(float)
    """
    d = np.zeros_like(f)
    # this loop misses the first and last points in f
    for i in range(1, f.shape[0]-1):
        # 2-point formula
        d[i] = (f[i+1] - f[i-1])/(2*h)

    return d

h = abs(xs[0] - xs[1]) # step size
y1 = deriv(y, h) # first derivative
y2 = deriv(y1, h) # second derivative
y3 = deriv(y2, h) # third derivative
```

When I plot `y,y1,y2,y3` you can see it blows up at the end points

[image]

What I have tried to do is set the end points to their nearest neighbors in `deriv` as below. While this works for low order derivatives (1st and 2nd) it starts to break at higher order derivatives (3rd and greater).

```
...
d = np.zeros_like(f)
for i in range(1, f.shape[0]-1):
    d[i] = (f[i+1] - f[i-1])/(2*h)

d[0] = d[1]
d[-1] = d[-2]
...
```

[image]

The derivative in the middle, away from the boundaries, is calculating fine. The issue is with the boundaries.

**How should I treat the boundary conditions here? Would a different numerical differentiation scheme work better than the central difference scheme?**

**EDIT:** I am looking for a general method to solve this, not just a method that can be applied to the sine function or any other periodic function as I have used to illustrate the issue here.

Comment: Ignore the extreme `x` values and their corresponding oddities.  Isn't that the usual approach ?  Or at least, one of the usual approaches ?  If you don't like that, extend `x` one step in -ve and +ve directions and ignore the extended extremities.  This isn't really a programming problem, it's more one of numerical analysis methodology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a numerical methods question than a programming question.

Anyways, if your function has periodic boundary conditions (it looks it is a sinusoidal wave so in this case you have periodicity) just create a new array with 2 additional elements: the new array start element will be your last element of the original array and the end element of the new array will be the start element of the original array. Here is a way to do it

```
f_periodic = np.zeros(f.size+2)
f_periodic[1:-1], f_periodic[0], f_periodic[-1] = f, f[-1], f[0]
```

You can now differentiate on `f_periodic` for which `d[1]` and `d[-2]` will be the correct derivative value on the boundaries (disregard `d[0]` and `d[-1]`) .

**Edit after OP's new requirements...**

For more general boundary conditions, say a specific value at the boundaries, there are different approaches one can follow:

1. Use ghost values:

Again extend the function and [extrapolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation) values for the new boundaries. Depending on the order of numerical differentiation more ghost cells will be required. For the current scheme, a simple linear extrapolation will do (only 1 ghost value at each boundary are required):

```
f_new = np.zeros(f.size+2)
f_new[1:-1] = f
f_new[-1] = f[-2] + (f[-2]-f[-3])/(x[-2]-x[-3])*(x[-1]-x[-2])
f_new[0] = f[1] + (f[1]-f[2])/(x[1]-x[2])*(x[0]-x[1])
```

Note that you have to also extend `x`. However, since you have a constant spacing just use `h` instead of spatial differences, e.g. `x[-2]-x[-3]`. You can now differentiate `f_new` and you will get an 1st-order approximation of the derivative on the boundaries (since you used a linear extrapolation to find the ghost value).

2. Use forwards and backwards schemes on the boundaries

I will not show code here, but basically you need to differentiate using an boundary value and the right (forwards) or left (backwards) value for the left and right boundaries respectively. This is a first-order approximation.

Comment: Thanks, but really I'm looking for a general solution, not just one with periodic b.c's. I use the sine function in my example here as it is easy to plot and verify if the calculated derivative is correct, but I want to extend this to more general functions

Comment: You mean functions with Dirichlet like boundary conditions (specific value at the boundaries)? And you did not specify this in your question, so I answered what you asked -.-

Comment: Don't [dirichlet b.c's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition) just apply to ODE's and PDE's? I'm just talking about taking higher and higher order derivatives of a function here.

Comment: They are useful for differentiation, precisely. Anyways, I will update my answer for more general boundary conditions.

Comment: Did the new answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the forward and backward differentiation scheme of order 2 for the boundary points. Essentially, we know that

```
(f(x+h)-f(x))/h = f'(x) + h/2*f''(x) + O(h²)                       (I)
```

and

```
(f(x+2h) - 2f(x+h) + f(x))/h² = f''(x+h) + O(h²) = f''(x) + O(h)   (II)
```

Use the last to replace the first order term with the second derivative, that is, compute `(I)-h/2*(II)` to get

```
(-1/2*f(x+2h) + 2*f(x+h) -3/2*f(x))/h = f'(x) + O(h²)
```

Note that the O(h²) error in the first derivative will in general lead to an O(h) error in the second iteration of the divided differences and O(1) in the third. One may argue that the error terms cancel suitably, but that will only happen for the inner points, the one-sided derivatives will "spoil" that pattern in increasing distance from the boundary.